# Locust, on_start method doesn't work with tasks

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I am trying to add some variables (e.g. self.boolean_flag) to HttpUser.
Which represents the user state. This variable is used in scenario load testing.

According to the documentation, I should use *on_start* to initialise variables.
However, when I use tasks = [TaskSet] like below, The on_start doesn't seem to work.

AttributeError: 'ExampleTask' object has no attribute 'boolean_flag':

```
class ExampleTask(TaskSet):
    @task
    def example_one(self):
        print(self.boolean_flag)   # AttributeError: 'ExampleTask' object has no attribute 'boolean_flag'
        make_api_request(self, "example_one")


class CustomUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(
        int(os.getenv("LOCUST_MIN_WAIT", 200)), int(os.getenv("LOCUST_MAX_WAIT", 1000))
    )

    def on_start(self):
        self.boolean_flag = False

    tasks = {ExampleTask1 : 10, ExampleTask2: 5 ... }
```

The bottom works though:

```
class CustomUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(
        int(os.getenv("LOCUST_MIN_WAIT", 200)), int(os.getenv("LOCUST_MAX_WAIT", 1000))
    )

    def on_start(self):
        self.boolean_flag = False

    @task
    def example_one(self):
        print(self.boolean_flag)
        make_api_request(self, "example_one")
```

Since I have many different scenarios that reuse many Tasksets, I need to use Tasks = {}..

I also tried subclassing HttpUser and add those variables in **init**().
But that doesn't work well with tasks={} either.

```
class CustomUser(HttpUser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.boolean_flag = False


class AllOfApisCallForLoadAtOneGo(CustomUser):
    wait_time = between(
    int(os.getenv("LOCUST_MIN_WAIT", 200)), int(os.getenv("LOCUST_MAX_WAIT", 1000))
)
    tasks = {ExampleTask1 : 10, ExampleTask2: 5 ... }
```

```
(loadtest-GvbsrA_X-py3.8) ➜  loadtest git:(abcd) ✗ locust -f locustfile_scenario.py first -H https://www.somehost.com
[2020-09-02 06:24:27,276] MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://0.0.0.0:8089 (accepting connections from all network interfaces)
[2020-09-02 06:24:27,286] MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 1.2.3
[2020-09-02 06:24:35,881] MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.runners: Spawning 10 users at the rate 3 users/s (0 users already running)...
[2020-09-02 06:24:35,883] MacBook-Pro.local/ERROR/locust.user.task: You must specify the base host. Either in the host attribute in the User class, or on the command line using the --host option.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/poetry/virtualenvs/loadtest-GvbsrA_X-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 284, in run
    self.execute_next_task()
  File "/Users/poetry/virtualenvs/loadtest-GvbsrA_X-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 309, in execute_next_task
    self.execute_task(self._task_queue.pop(0))
  File "/Users/poetry/virtualenvs/loadtest-GvbsrA_X-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 422, in execute_task
    task(self.user)
  File "/Users/poetry/virtualenvs/loadtest-GvbsrA_X-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/users.py", line 224, in __init__
    raise LocustError(
locust.exception.LocustError: You must specify the base host. Either in the host attribute in the User class, or on the command line using the --host option.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're assuming that `TaskSet` inherits from or somehow otherwise is called directly from `HttpUser`, which isn't the case. But TaskSet does have the user passed into it when it's instantiated. You just have to use `self.user`. So in your case instead of `print(self.boolean_flag)` in your task, you'd do `print(self.user.boolean_flag)`.